# Flutter status bar color with SafeArea in iOS

Tags: flutter, statusbar

I am using the following code for coloring the status bar in flutter.

```
void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
  value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.blue),
  child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'My App',
    theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
    home: MyHomeScreen(),
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  ),
);
}}

class MyHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
const MyHomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Header(), // my own custom header
  ),
);
}
}
```

With the above code I am getting the desired result in Android but in iOS the status bar is still showing in white color.
I have tried [this link](https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-flutter/) but I am not getting the desired solution for iOS.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had also same issue. i found solution with [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor_ns).

try that package.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following lines to your code ,

```
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: any Color),
    );
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
```

It'll change the whole app's status bar color :)

**UPDATE:**

you can use this trick to achieve status bar color in Ios

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
       color: any color,
       child: SafeArea(
       child: Scaffold(
  body: Header(), // my own custom header
     ),
   ),
  );
}
```